# jQuery: Backstretch with Blurjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using [Backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/) to display my background image. Then I want to use [Blur.js](http://blurjs.com/) to have elements blur the background. Using blur.js on the backstretched image doesn't work. I assume it is because Blur.js uses the CSS property background-image and Backstretch just displays the image with .

How do I make these two compatible?
The code inside of these plugins is pretty complicated.

Comment: I think we're going to need to see some code that you've worked on.

Answer (score 1):

This might do what you need (not using blur.js). Just adding some CSS blurring to the div backstretch creates.

```
<style>
    div.backstretch {
      -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
      -moz-filter: blur(5px);
      -o-filter: blur(5px);
      -ms-filter: blur(5px);
      filter: blur(5px);

      margin: -10px; /* Added to get rid of white blur borders */
    }
</style>
```

Comment: blurring the background makes scrolling really-really slow (even though the bg is fixed)